GTM tag does not fire when using gtag.js function
I am having trouble getting my GTM tags to fire consistently. I'm using the gtag.js function gtag() to fire a tag when a user clicks a button on my page.
I don't always see those tags on Google Analytics, so I went to GTM Preview tool to check out what is wrong. When looking at the preview, this is what I see for a particular tag that I'm testing. Keep in mind that I have GDPR protection set up, but I consented to the cookies, so I'm loading all the gtag/gtm scripts.
First image is what I see when I am on the GTM container, when I click on the tag triggered:

First thing that looks odd is that the 'Tags Not Fired' section contains the GA4 configuration. In GTM, we have this tag set with the measurement ID to fire on all pages.
Moving on, these are the details when I click on the GA4 Configuration tag in the not fired section:

I can see that the firing triggers have not been met, but I'm not sure what that means, I'm not familiar with GTM that much as I'm a developer.
Also, when I click on the GA measurement ID above and I click on this event, this is what I see:

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to fix/change in order to get the tags to fire and for them to show up in GA?

There should be two tags:
One for GA4 configuration.
Another one for GA4 event.

You need to trigger GA4 configuration with the All Pages trigger first.
Then fire the event tag based on when you want to fire the GA4 event tag.
Because we can not tell saving_sns_outbound is if user interact with something on the website.

I want to trigger the saving_sns_outbound event when a user clicks on a button, and I have a similar website where it all works, but for some reason this is not going through. I don't want to create a new tag for every event, since those events are dynamic and based on values from the database.
